# Delphi Indy 10 IdHTTPProxyServer Modifying Headers

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I am trying to develop a CORS proxy server in Delphi XE2 using Indy 10 so that I can get around the issue of embedding sites into an IFrame where sites have added X-Frame-Options to the response headers.

Can anyone give me some example code as to how I can use IdHTTPProxyServer to do this?

Comment: "*how I can use IdHTTPProxyServer to do this?*" - To do WHAT, exactly? What exactly do you want to modify? Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau From what I understand, the goal is to remove the `X-Frame-Options` header.

Comment: Modifying headers in `TIdHTTPProxyServer` is fairly easy (see my answer). But, you do realize that, in order for this to work at all, users will have to reconfigure their browsers to connect through your proxy, don't you? Are you sure this is the option you want to pursue? Or, are you looking for a more transparent solution?

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry I should have been more specific.  Yes the intention as indicated by Olivier is to remove the X-Frame-Options in the header so I can embed a website into an Iframe.  Yes I am also aware it would need the users to configure their proxy settings.  Can you elaborate more on what you mean by a transparent solution?

Comment: @user2365039 "*Can you elaborate more on what you mean by a transparent solution?*" - meaning one that doesn't require browser reconfiguration, it "just works" behind the scenes for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes that would be the ideal scenario.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When using `TIdHTTPProxyServer`, you can modify HTTP headers for `GET`/`POST`/`HEAD` requests only, in the following events:

- `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event (client headers)
- `OnHTTPResponse` event (server headers)
- `OnHTTPDocument` event (client or server headers, depending on the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.TransferSource` property) when the proxy's `DefaultTransferMode` property is set to `tmFullDocument`.

The headers are stored in the `Headers` property of the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext` object provided to each event.

For example, using the `OnHTTPResponse` event, you can easily remove an `X-Frame-Options` header, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPResponse(AContext: TIdHTTPProxyServerContext);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := AContext.Headers.IndexOfName('X-Frame-Options');
  if I <> -1 then
    AContext.Headers.Delete(I);
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPResponse(AContext: TIdHTTPProxyServerContext);
begin
  AContext.Headers.Values['X-Frame-Options'] := '';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ProcessHTTPRequest - Resp: TIdHTTPResponseInfo - you can add this line to set the http header response:

```
Resp.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Frame-Options'] := 'Deny';
```

Works with the normal indy http server, should work with the proxy as well.
In the same way you can set it to empty, or other values.

I came upon your post looking for a way to "add" it - i'm hoping this answer helps others who are looking for similar information, even if the actual answer isn't exactly what you're looking for in the OP.